# Getting UTC UNIX timestamp in Lua

Tags: datetime, time, lua, timestamp, strftime

An API returns a timestamp as UNIX timestamp at UTC and I would like to know if this timestamp was more than `x` seconds ago. As expected, this works fine with `os.time() - x > timestamp` in UTC, but blows up in other timezones.

Unfortunately I can't find a good way solve this in lua.

`os.date` helpfully has the `!` prefix (e.g. `os.date("!%H:%M:%S")`) to return time at UTC, but it seems that despite the documentation stating it supports all `strftime` options, this does not support the `%s` option. I have heard people mention that this is caused by Lua compile time options for a similar issue, but changing these is not possible as the interpreter is provided by the user.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use

`os.time(os.date("!*t"))`

to get the current UNIX epoch.

Comment: ohh that makes a lot of sense. I had tried it the other way around and I couldn't get it to do anything useful!

Comment: a note on performance: This is around 500x slower than taking os.time() and subtracting the difference. However because I anticipate bugs with that approach and expect max msg/sec to be around 200 I will go with this.

Comment: Glad you measured.

Comment: Actually, it fails on my system. linux `date` returns 14:40, `date -u` returns 12:40, but lua `os.time(os.date("!*t"))` returns 1562240400 which corresponds to 13:40, so it seems there are timezone/DST issues

Comment: `os.time(os.date("*t"))` works without DST issue

Answer (score 6):

Ok, so you want the UTC time. Keep in mind that `os.time` actually **[knows nothing about timezones](https://www.lua.org/pil/22.1.html)**, so for example:

```
os.time(os.date("!*t"))
```

1. Will get UTC time and populate table struct.
2. Will convert table struct according to current timezone to unix timestamp.

So you actually would get your UNIX_TIME - TIMEZONE_OFFSET. If you are in GMT+5 you will get timestamp at UTC-5.

The correct way to do time conversion in lua is:

```
os.time() -- get current epoch value
os.time{ ... } -- get epoch value for local date/time values
os.date("*t"),os.date("%format") -- get your local date/time
os.date("!*t") or os.date("!%format") -- get UTC date/time
os.date("*t", timestamp),os.date("%format", timestamp) -- get your local date/time for given timestamp
os.date("!*t", timestamp) or os.date("!%format", timestamp) -- get UTC date/time for given timestamp
```

Kudos to [Mons](https://gist.github.com/Mons) at https://gist.github.com/ichramm/5674287.

If you really need to convert any UTC date to timestamp, there's a good description on how to do this in this question: [Convert a string date to a timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105012/convert-a-string-date-to-a-timestamp)

Answer (score 0):

`os.time()` gives you the unix timestamp. The timestamp is seconds since 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970, so it's the same across timezones.

For example, run this code:

```lua
print('timestamp', os.time())
print('local hour', os.date("*t").hour)
print('utc hour', os.date("!*t").hour)
```

Presumably, your local and utc hour are different. [Also run it in an online repl](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/oCgzr0RDvSQzN7W4JDG3QF1HIb9YD8TV0NTkgsrm5Ccn5ihk5JcWQaRTEktSNZS0SpQ09UCCcHWlJckYqhQRyv7/BwA). The server's local and utc hour are the same, but both your and the server's timestamp are about the same.